# Parameters cause sql query to time out

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, parameters

I have a long SQL query, it does some inserts, updates, then deletes. Each query uses the same 2 parameters. If I pass them in as SQL parameters from C#, it times out, after 20 mins. I just put the parameters into the command text, and it works. When I use it with the parameters it doesn't even show up in the profiler till it times out. Am I missing something?

```
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn); 
comm.CommandTimeout = 5 * 60; 
SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter("@key1", SqlDbType.Int);
p.Value = key1;
comm.Parameters.Add(p);
p = new SqlParameter("@key2", SqlDbType.Int);
p.Value = 1000000;
comm.Parameters.Add(p);
comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

If you take the parameter code out, and just to a replace on cmdText before executing the query it works. The query itself is a 300 lines or so. Each parameter gets used 51 times.

Comment: You might want to show us your c# code

Comment: Post some source. If the query isn't showing in the profiler until it times out, it's not being submitted.

Comment: You should check if you are getting only SQL Stmt Completed in your profiler or if you are also getting the SQL Stmt Started as well.

Comment: You say you are doing a number of inserts, updates, deletes in a row... command preparation can bite you sometimes. Are you reusing the same command object or creating a new command object every time? If you have the same SQL inside a command that you execute a bunch, it can save time to keep the command object around until you are done.

Comment: Side note: if you're using SQL Server 2008, look into using the Merge statement along with a table-valued parameter. This can clean up your code quite a bit when updating/inserting/deleting lots of records for a single table based on bulk client-side changes.

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing the comm.Prepare() call before ExecuteNonQuery().

The key is in the SQL command, instead of saying "cmdText" post your SQL command.

EDIT: You are also not specifying a parameter direction in the code, it might be important.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the command type?

```
var command = new SqlCommand() { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure };
```